# return true or false finding substring

Tags: erlang

I'm just figuring out control flows, its all very strange and confusing since I've never used a functional language before, could someone correct this for me:

```
-export([main/1, test/2]).

main([]) -> 
   if 
      test("blue yellow green", "yellow") == true ->
          {io:fwrite("found")};
      true ->
          {io:fwrite("not found")}
   end.


test(Source, Find) ->
    Pos = string:str(Source, Find),
    if
       Pos > 1 ->
            {true};  
       true ->
            {false}
    end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corrected version:

```
-module(test).
-export([main/0, test/2]).

main() ->
    case test("blue yellow green", "yellow") of
        true -> io:fwrite("found~n");
        false -> io:fwrite("not found~n")
    end.

test(Source, Find) ->
    Pos = string:str(Source, Find),
    if
        Pos > 1 ->
            true;
        true ->
            false
    end.
```

When you return just one element, you shouldn't use `{` and `}`.

Comment: I'd probably use a `case string:str(Source, Find) of P when P >= 1 -> true; 0 -> false end` here or something like that

Comment: Or even just `string:str(Source, Find) >= 1.`

Comment: There is only 1 problem with this answer.  If the string looks like this you will still get a 0 back `string:str("blue yellow green", "blue").`. It's not a big problem if you know what you are looking for will never be starting at char 0.